# Adding Roles to Rails Composer, Devise, CanCan, Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, cancan, rails-console, rolify

I am making an app that started with [Rails Composer, Devise, CanCan, Twitter Bootstrap.](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan)

I know how to set the users permissions using the ability model. How do I add more roles to attribute certain permissions to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find any help during my search, so here is what I came up with on my own.

Somewhere between rolify and rails composer, a Role table is made.

1. Enter the rails console

   ```
   $ rails c
   ```
2. Add your new role

   ```
   irb> Role.create name: 'new-role'
   ```

*Use this to display all of your roles

```
    irb> Role.all
```

*To Delete Roles

```
    irb> Role.delete(role_id)
```